# How would I convert AircraftData[] to an Entity[] that could be used with ImageIdentify[]?

Tags: image-processing, entity

I am working on a Design of Experiments to determine the image adjustment settings for a given collection of aircraft images to maximize the probabilities of correctly identifying the aircraft types using `ImageIdentify`.

The *> Neat Example* for `ImageIdentify` in the documentation shows the use of a category `Entity["Word", "car"]`.

When I use `Entity["Word", "aircraft"]`, the identification is by broad aircraft type. I would like the probabilities by the entries in `AircraftData[]` so that I could see the probability that the image is an `F-15 Eagle`, `F/A-18 Hornet`, etc.

```
ImageIdentify[f15image, Entity["Word", "aircraft"],10, "Probability"]
```

Returns

```
<|Entity["Concept", "Interceptor::zff3s"] -> 0.74917, 
 Entity["Concept", "AttackAircraft::548v5"] -> 0.755533, 
 Entity["Concept", "StealthFighter::54q24"] -> 0.00636256, 
 Entity["Concept", "MilitaryPlane::whx2r"] -> 0.75629, 
 Entity["Concept", "Aeroplane::239dv"] -> 0.999771, 
 Entity["Concept", "JumboJet::558sx"] -> 0.12094, 
 Entity["Concept", "Floatplane::5wd4t"] -> 0.0944084, 
 Entity["Concept", "Jetliner::p464v"] -> 0.0241423, 
 Entity["Concept", "FlyingBoat::t75c7"] -> 0.00215588, 
 Entity["Concept", "JetPlane::q8z95"] -> 0.145083|>
```

I would like to use `ImageIdentify` with `AircraftData[]` or `EntityList["Aircraft"]` to see if it can identify specific aircraft types. None of my attempts to date have succeeded.

```
ImageIdentify[F15, Entity["Aircraft"], 10, "Probability"]
```

Returns

```
Entity["Aircraft"] is not a valid object.
```

- I am working through the article on [Resolving my Entity Crisis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103193/resolving-my-entity-crisis).
- A hierarchical diagram that shows the relationships between the *Entity...* functions and terminology would be most helpful.

Do I need to create a custom entity store to make this possible?

Comment: Have you seen this question: [Why does ImageRecognition recognise some concepts in a list of concepts but not others?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282055/why-does-imagerecognition-recognise-some-concepts-in-a-list-of-concepts-but-not) `ImageIdentify` uses a pretrained neural network to give predictions from a preset list of entities/concepts. If you want to include more of them, you have to train your own neural network with relevant image examples.

Comment: I think that is part of it. I need to dig into the `Entity...` functions and terminology. This is not intuitive. I am sure that I will need to train my own neural network using Janes and other sources. What is here is neat to a point - but not to the level that I need.

Comment: So I assume you already have a large annotated collection of aircraft images? In that case, you can simply use [`Classify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Classify.html) on this set of data, and you will get a classifier which you can then use on other, unannotated images.

Comment: I will experiment with `Classify`. I may try to use the `Name` and `Image` properties of  `AircraftData[]`. Barring that I will use a database of aircraft types.